# How to get result with additional filtered related objects as a field in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-orm

I want to get all data in one query, so I need to add some field result from related object by the filter of it (Not by the parent object filter).

```py
def get_queryset(self):
        return Mailbox.objects\
            .filter(owner=self.request.user.id)\
            .prefetch_related('letter_set')\
            .annotate(
                new_letter_count=Count(
                    'letter',
                    filter=Q(letter__read_at=None)
                ),
                total_count=Count('letter'),
                latest_letter_datetime=Max('letter__created_at'),


                ### #################### ###
                ### THE QUESTION IS HERE ###
                ### #################### ###

                latest_letter_CONTENT= #(What code here could be work?)#

                ### I wnat to get the latest letter content


            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll answer this assuming that there is a `ForeignKey` in the model `Letter` pointing to the model `MailBox`.

You might use a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) for that:

```
# I'm assuming here a couple of things:
# The fields content and date_created exist in your Letter model, 
# if there is no date created field, use instead whatever you are using for
# establish some sort of order creation.
MailBox.objects.annotate(
    last_letter_content = Subquery(
        Letter.objects.filter(mailbox=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date_created').values('content')[:1]
    )
)
```